# How to run unitests of the form test/a.py?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, project

Is it possible to implement a Python project with a file structure like the following?:

```
myproj
├── a.py
├── b.py
├── c.py
└── test/
    ├── a.py
    ├── b.py
    └── c.py
```

Note, in particular, that the test scripts under `test/` have the same basenames as the module files they are testing  <sup>1</sup>.  (In other words, `test/a.py` contains the unit tests for `a.py`; `test/b.py` contains those for `b.py`, etc.)

The tests under `test/` all import `unittest` and define subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`.

I want to know how to run the tests under `test/`, both individually, and all together.

I've tried many variations of `python -m unittest ...`, but they all either fail (examples below), or end up running zero tests.

For example,

```
% python -m unittest test.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'
```

If I change the name of the `test/` directory to `t/`, then the error becomes:

```
% python -m unittest t.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
ImportError: No module named t
```

Or

```
% python -m unittest t/a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

(I am using Python 2.7.9.)

---

**UPDATE**

Since I put a bounty on this question, I'll be very explicit about what would constitute an acceptable answer.

Either one of the following would be acceptable:

- How to invoke `unittest` from the command line to run either individual tests, or all the tests under the `test/` directory; it is acceptable for solution to entail small changes to the code in the test scripts (e.g. modifications to the import statements).
- If the file structure shown above is not possible for some reason, a detailed explanation would be an acceptable solution.

As a base case, start with the following minimal case with the following file structure:

```
myproj
├── a.py
├── b.py
└── test/
    ├── a.py
    └── b.py
```

...and the following contents

```
# a.py
def hello():
    print 'hello world'
```

```
# b.py
def bye():
    print 'good-bye world'
```

```
# test/a.py

import unittest
import a

class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_hello(self):
        self.assertEqual(a.hello(), None)
```

```
# test/b.py

import unittest
import b

class TestB(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bye(self):
        self.assertEqual(b.bye(), None)
```

Show how one tells `unittest` to run the test `test/a.py`, and how to run "all the tests under `test`".  (The latter should continue to work, even if the new test scripts are added to `test`, or some of the current test scripts are removed.)

---

Minimal tests of the proposals offered so far show that they don't work.  For example:

```
% python -m unittest discover -s test -p '*.py'
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_hello (a.TestA)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/SHIVAMJINDAL/myproj/test/a.py", line 6, in test_hello
    self.assertEqual(a.hello(), None)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hello'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_bye (b.TestB)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/SHIVAMJINDAL/myproj/test/b.py", line 6, in test_bye
    self.assertEqual(b.bye, None)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bye'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=2)
% tree .
.
├── a.py
├── b.py
├── __init__.py
└── test/
    ├── a.py
    ├── b.py
    └── __init__.py

1 directory, 6 files
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This constraint is very much intentional, and it is an integral part of the problem presented here.  (IOW, a "solution" that entails relaxing this constraint is in fact not a solution.)</sup>

Comment: the path to the module files is not known in the subdirectory test/. You need to make that path available by sys.path.append ("..").

Comment: If you don;t get this going with unittest, try pytest. https://pypi.org/project/pytest/  It will run the unittest test cases just fine, and is generally much easier to interact with.

Comment: Please provide the import statement of tests files.

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL: that's part of the question; IOW, the answer to this question may specify how the tests import the tested modules.  (The import for `unittest` is just `import unittest`.)

Comment: you are getting error that "no module named ..." which module it is? Is it you file a,b or c or unittest module.

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL: I updated my post to give more complete information, and to include some examples that hopefully answer your question.

Comment: @kjo, you have not provided feedback on any of the answers in the question. Please do that before the bounty expires, so many times effort from everyone gets wasted because the OP doesn't respond and accept the answer on time

Comment: @TarunLalwani: I'm following the post closely, and will accept an answer during the grace period.

Comment: @kjo, Thanks. Just wanted to make sure you are attending to everyone

Answer (score 7):

I was able to make your approach work, but there are few changes that are needed and mandatory.

1. The test should be run with a parent directory context
2. Both main folder and test folder should have a `__init__.py`
3. The imports in the tests should be a relative import and not a direct import

So below is my tree structure

```
root@5db7ad85dafd:/project# tree
.
 __init__.py
 a.py
 test
     __init__.py
     a.py

1 directory, 4 files

root@5db7ad85dafd:/project# python --version
Python 2.7.9
```

**project/a.py**

```
hello = 'tarun'
```

**project/test/a.py**

```
import unittest
from .. import a

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_abc(self):
       assert a.hello == "tarun"
```

Notice the `from .. import a` which is import for this to work

Next we run the test being in the root folder of the project like below

```
root@5db7ad85dafd:/project# python -m unittest discover -t .. -s test -p "*.py"
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

`-t` here sets the top level import directory, so our relative imports can work
`-s` tells which directory our tests are in
`-p` tells what patter the test should be discovered in

When you want to run a individual test you will do something like below

```
python -m unittest discover -t .. -s test -p "a.py"
```

or

```
python -m unittest discover -t .. -s test -p "*.py" a
```

A picture is always worth more than words

[image: Unit Tests working]

**Edit-1**

Wanted to update my answer after seeing Peter's answer. The reason I didn't mention the import from a fixed named package was that it would mean that you need to know the name of the folder where the code is cloned and it is enforced to remain the same. But if you still want to go with that approach, then one approach is to move the actual into a sub-folder

So it would be `repo/project/test/a.py` and then in your tests you will use

```
from project import a
```

and then run it like below from the repo folder

```
root@5db7ad85dafd:/repo# python -m unittest discover -v -t project -s project.test -p "*.py"
test_abc (test.a.TestStringMethods) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

or like below from the test folder

```
root@5db7ad85dafd:/repo/project# python -m unittest discover -v -t .. -s test -p "*.py"
test_abc (project.test.a.TestStringMethods) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

In this case moving your project folder one level from root, will make sure that the project name is not dependent on the folder where your project is cloned

Comment: If `myproj` is supposed to be a package, then it should not be the top-level in the source code repository in the first place. At which point you can put your tests directory **next** to the package. This is what all the major Python projects do.

Answer (score 2):

Tarun's answer is already pretty complete...  In short:

1. You must make your modules importable (by creating `__init__.py` files)
2. You must tell the interpreter exactly where to look to prevent the naming clash between your modules.

The import doesn't have to be relative, though.  Assuming that your project is going to be packaged up the import could (arguably, should) be precisely as you would expect users of your package to use - e.g. `from myproj import a`.

At this point I have also got `python -m unittest discover -t .. -s test -p '*.py'` to work.  But this is the point where I get fed up with the extra hoops that the basic `unittest` package places on the user.  I'd also recommend that once you have made the 2 changes, you also install `nosetests` (strictly speaking the python `nose` package) as it generally makes life easier for you to find and run the tests.

For example:

```
$ tree
.
├── a.py
├── a.pyc
├── b.py
├── b.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
└── test
    ├── a.py
    ├── a.pyc
    ├── b.py
    ├── b.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __init__.pyc

1 directory, 12 files
$ cat test/a.py
# test/a.py

import unittest
from myproj import a

class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_hello(self):
        self.assertEqual(a.hello(), None)
$ nosetests test/*.py
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the structure you show in your question is like that you are using some IDE such as Pycharm before.

In Pycharm, you absolutely can have that project structure. As you can run `unittest` in a single file by just right-clicking it and clicking `Run 'unittest in a.py'`. And you can run `unittest` in whole directory by right-clicking on directory and click `Run 'unittest in test'`.

Further, you needn't to create a `__ini__.py` in `test` to make it become a module and importable. Also you can directly `import your_lib` in test file without worrying about import path problem.

All of these are done by the magic of IDE, so you cannot directly achieve this only using `python -m unittest ...`. If you can, why does Pycharm use a helper named `_jb_unittest_runner.py`?

But you can create a simple bash script to achieve similar behave.

The keys are:

- Assign project root to a variable such as `PROJECT_HOME`.
- Assign test root to a variable such as `TEST_HOME`.
- Add `PROJECT_HOME` to `PYTHONPATH` so that you can directly import your project in test files.
- Change your working directory to `${TEST_HOME}`
- Use `python -m unittest ${PROJECT_HOME}/test/${file_name}` to run a
  single file.
- Use `python -m unittest discover -s ${PROJECT_HOME}/test -t
  ${PROJECT_HOME}/test` to run a whole directory.
- Use `python -m unittest ${file_name}.${test_case}` to run a single test case.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to implement a Python project with a file structure
>   like the following?

I don't think this structure would be usable in the way you are trying. In this apporach, the root problem is the module names conflict  in your tests.

For example, the statement `import a` in your test case 'test\a.py' resolve to the module `test\a` instead of referring to *module under test* (a.py)

Since you want to name your test modules exactly same as the *module under test*, one possible solution could by that you move all your modules under a package and the change  import statement in your test. For example:

```
+---python2unittest
¦       a.py
¦       b.py
¦       __init__.py
+---test
¦   ¦   a.py
¦   ¦   b.py
```

Your test case, test/a.py will look like:

```
import unittest

from python2unittest import a


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_hello(self):
        self.assertEqual(a.hello(), None)
```

How to run tests from command line:

```
python -m unittest discover -s  -t test -p a.py  // Specific Test
python -m unittest discover -s  -t test -p *.py  // All tests
```

Note:- If you have sub-directories for your test files, you need to add the `__init__.py` file in each sub-directory so that all test files can be discovered by unittest.

More information on test discovery can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery):

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have `__init__.py` file under your python package myproj and test. that's you are not able to import a module in test of a.

Please add blank `__init__.py` file in test and myproj directory both. If this does not solve the problem, please provide code of any test file.

You have used import b in your test/b.py file but it should be from myproj import b. Because if you are using just import b it will import the current file (in which you have written the test and this file does not have any bye() method). So either you can change the file name of your test files or use below code.

```
# test/b.py

import unittest
from myproj import b

class TestB(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bye(self):
        self.assertEqual(b.bye(), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain your issue is that you run Python 2.7, where doing a plain `import a` is ambiguous wether a means the one relative to the current module or from the base path. Add the line
`from __future__ import absolute_import` to the top of your files (it has to be the first non-comment line). I'd recommend you do it on all files, but it should be enough to do it on the test/*.py files.

Once done, you should be able to run
`python -m unittest discover -s test -p '*.py'`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirements some time ago (python 2.6) and I ended up implementing a little executable script that will run your tests (call it `run_tests`, code below) by loading modules dynamically based on file paths.

The only change that you **will** have to make is to put your source modules into a package, which makes a lot of sense since you want to import these source modules from your test modules.

If you really want to have your source modules in the root of your project, it is possible with this solution as well, but you will then have to rename your test modules to something different (like `test_a.py` for instance). I can tweak the current solution to make this work if you want me to.

Your project structure needs to look like this:

```
.
├── project
│   ├── a.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── test
    ├── a.py
    └── run_tests
```

Here, `project` is the package containing your source `a.py`, remember, to make it a package, the `project` folder needs an empty `__init__.py` file in it.

Now the content of `run_tests`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fnmatch
import imp
import os
import sys
import unittest

append_lib = lambda p: sys.path.append(p)
root_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "..")
test_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, "test")

append_lib(root_dir) # packages to be tested are to be found there

def find_files():
  matches = []
  for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(test_dir):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.py"):
      matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
  return matches

def module_from_path(path):
  module = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
  return imp.load_source(module, path)

def run_tests_in_paths(paths):
  suite = unittest.TestSuite()
  for p in paths:
    s = unittest.findTestCases(module_from_path(p))
    suite.addTests(s)
  if not unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite).wasSuccessful():
    raise RuntimeError("some test cases failed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    paths = sys.argv[1:]
    print "> Running %s individual test file%s" % (len(paths), "s" if len(paths) > 1 else "")
    run_tests_in_paths(sys.argv[1:])
  else:
    print "> Running complete test suite"
    run_tests_in_paths(find_files())
```

I tested this setup with this content for `project/a.py`:

```
class A(object):
  pass
```

And for `test/a.py`:

```
import unittest

from project import a

class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_hello(self):
    self.assertNotEqual(a.A(), None)
```

You can now run the `run_tests` script (do not forget to `chmod +x` it) like this for a single file:

```
./test/run_tests test/a.py
```

Or like that to run any test modules in the `test` folder:

```
./test/run_tests
```

Note: do not hesitate to improve / customize the `run_tests` scripts to better fit your needs.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You'd better package your app the `setuptools` way, this would make things easier with a regular package files layout.

Anayway you should try the auto discover mode:

- put an `test/__init__.py` file. Even empty.
- put a class inheriting `unittest.TestCase` in `test/anything.py` with `test_xxx` method(s)
- `cd root/of/project`
- `python -m unittest discover -s test -p *.py`

See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#test-discovery about the used options.