# When is cwd in PYTHONPATH needed?

Tags: python, python-import

I am working at the top of my project. In some environments, I can simply:

```
from cslib.svc import SVC
```

without problems.

In others:

```
    from cslib.svc import SVC
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cslib'
```

In each case, `PYTHONPATH` is not set, and I am at the top of my project.

Setting `PYTHONPATH=.` solves the problem, but I would like to understand why in some cases this is needed, and why in some cases it is not.

Here it works:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

Here it works also:

```
» python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Here it doesn't:

```
» python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

But I am not convinced this problem is version related.

When / why do we need to add the `cwd` to `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: cslib is a directory present in the folder you are running python? If so, you should do a relative import.

Comment: @MaximeChéramy - that would assume that the parent of cwd is a package (there is a sibling `__init__.py`) and that the module doing the import was itself import (so its part of the package) instead of being run as a script (its not part of the package).

Comment: Python usually adds `''` to the top of `sys.path`. It would be interesting to  print that list to see what it is in the failing case.

Comment: @MaximeChéramy cslib is a directory containing all  python sources for my project. The tests are in `tests/...`. All test modules access the sources by doing `from cslib.svc import SVC` and similar. I assume that python can import `cslib`. That assumption is usually satisfied without the need to set `PYTHONPATH`, as long as I start the interpreter in the top dir. But sometimes this is not true. Why?

Comment: @tdelaney what does "usually" mean? Is this documented? This could be related to my problem ...

Comment: @tdelaney there is no `__init__.py` in the cwd.

Comment: See my related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322414/5588279 Without magic you cannot import `cslib` directly as it is beyond your tests' top module.

Comment: Its been standard in python for a long time. I don't remember quite when in the load process its inserted or how that may break, but I'll do some poking around.

Comment: @Sraw not true, as long as I start the tests on the parent directory, as in `py.test`. `py.test` will discover tests, and since I am working on the top dir, importing of `cslib` will simply work ... *usually*. Why does this sometimes break?

Comment: I think you need provide more information such as your directories structure, where do you run your cmd, what is your cmd... and so on.

Comment: My next step would be to `print sys.path` in the three cases to see the differences.

Comment: Okay, I stated that kinda wrong. It will add the path where your script resides to the path if you do `python somescript.py`. It has several rules depending on whether you use the `-c` and `-m` options. See https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html. just search for `sys.path`.