# Cannot run unittest in PyCharm

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pycharm

When I try to run a unittest with PyCharm I have an error that I didn't manage to solve :

`python3.6: No module named _jb_unittest_runner`

My test module looks like (in a folder with **init**.py):

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, True)
```

I found no information about this module and how to install it.

Do you know what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The main reason for the error is Python can't import your module because it's not on `sys.path`. There are [several posts on the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bunit-testing%5D+%22No+module+named%22+-pytest). I think the direct answer is given [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322414) The problem is you aren't giving us enough information about your project layout and environment. You'll see the answers on the other threads all focus on how the project is organized.

Answer (score 0):

Python comes bundled with unittest:

Your code is missing main method.

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

or you can also pass your file to unitest module

```
python3 -m unittest py_file.py
```

-v for verbose output.

Comment: I forgot to mention that but my file contains this method which was autogenerated by PyCharm :/